# How to Upload images to a Logged In User and Get User images PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I want to **upload** and **get** data of **Logged In** user same like **Facebook** and **Twitter** . Here what my code is doing is, it retrieves all the images posted by different users after logged in. **Please help me. What i want is if user is logged in , profile page should get the data of only the user who is logged in and not all the users data and how to insert image values for a user in mysql.**

**Here is my SQL tabeles User and Posts**

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `hash` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `image` varchar(200) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

**Posts SQL**

```
  CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

Here is php code in **Profile.php**

```
    <?php 
    session_start();
    include 'ssql.php';
    require 'db.php';

    // Check if user is logged in using the session variable
    if ( $_SESSION['logged_in'] != 1 ) {
      $_SESSION['message'] = "You must log in before viewing your profile page!";
      header("location: error.php");    
    }
    else {
        // Makes it easier to read
        $first_name = $_SESSION['first_name'];
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];
        $email = $_SESSION['email'];
        $active = $_SESSION['active'];

    }
    ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" width="device-width">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fcb.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var flag = 0;   
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "get_data.php",
data: {
'offset':0,
'limit' :10
},
success: function(data){
$('#post1').html(data);


flag += 10
}

});

$(window).scroll(function() {

if($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {    
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "get_data.php",
data: {
'offset': flag,
'limit' : 10
},
success: function (data) {
$('#post1').append(data);

flag += 10;
}

}); 

}
});
});
</script>    
<body>
<div id="post1">
</div>
</body>
```

Here is database **db.php**

```
<?php
/* Database connection settings */
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db = 'accounts';
$mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db) or die($mysqli->error);
```

Here is the code for uploads of posts **ssql.php**

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['update'])){


header('Location:profile.php'); 

$target = "images/".basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "accounts");
$image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$data = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT `id` FROM `user`");
$sql = "insert into posts (userid, image) values ('$userid', '$image')";
mysqli_query($db, $sql);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)) { 

} else {

}

}



?>
```

Here is **get_data.php** to retrieve images

```
<?php

session_start();
include_once("db.php");
include_once("ssql.php");

if(isset($_GET['offset']) && isset($_GET['limit'])){

$limit = $_GET['limit'];
$offset = $_GET['offset'];  
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'accounts');
$data = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT `image` FROM `posts` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT {$limit} OFFSET {$offset} ");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
    echo "<div id='post1'>";
    echo "<img src='images/".$row['image']."' >";
    echo "</div>";
}
}
?>
```

**Please help me. What i want is if user is logged in , profile page should get the data of only the user who is logged in and not all the users data and how to insert image values for a user in mysql.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the condition for the user id in the query, like this:

```
$data = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT `image` FROM `posts` WHERE userid={$loggedInUserId} ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT {$limit} OFFSET {$offset} ");
```

Comment: how to insert image values for a user in mysql

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['update'])){
 $target = "images/".basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
 if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)) { 
  $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "accounts");
  $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
  $userid = $_SESSION['user_id']; //Use the user id that you have set
  $sql = "insert into posts (userid, image) values ('$userid', '$image')";
  mysqli_query($db, $sql);
  header('Location:profile.php');  
 }
}`

Comment: i am getting same user posts if i login with any user please help me

Comment: please check ssql.php and get_data.php above mentioned.

Comment: Please change the query as I have mentioned above.

Comment: Yes i have used the code above mentioned but if i login with any user its getting same posts to all users. i want like facebook or twitter than a user gets his own posts in his time line.

Comment: How you set the value of `$loggedInUserId` variable which is passed in the query?

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: loggedInUserId in C:\xampp\htdocs\login-system\get_data.php on line 15

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\login-system\get_data.php on line 16. iam getting this error if i set the value $loggedInUserId

Comment: Get the user id from the session and set the $loggedInUserId with that, like:
`$loggedInUserId = $_SESSION['user_id']; //Or the index you have used for user id in the session variable.`

Comment: Thanks a ton it helped me :)